# I am having trouble getting the emulator to work

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have followed the instructions found online on my laptop and my desktop.  My desktop works fine  but my laptop gives me the following errors when I try to run the emulator through eclipse.  The device 'and' is listed and the preferences point to the correct file.

emulator: ERROR: unknown virtual device name: 'and'
emulator: could not find virtual device named 'and'

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using Windows or Linux or Mac... ?

On my linux machine, when a new virtual device is created, it would create (for a 'and' device) a file in ~/.android/avd/and.ini and folder as ~/.android/avd/and.avd with several .img files. Maybe you should check those files are there and have the right permissions also ?